# chartjs and patternomally in storybook not working

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, storybook

I have chartjs 3.7.0 and patternomaly 1.3.2 with react 16.14.0. I am trying to draw chart with pattern like below,

```
datasets: [{
  data: [
    300, 50, 100, 210, 140
  ],
  backgroundColor: [
    pattern.draw('square', '#1f77b4'),
    pattern.draw('circle', '#ff7f0e'),
    pattern.draw('diamond', '#2ca02c'),
    pattern.draw('zigzag-horizontal', '#17becf'),
    pattern.draw('triangle', 'rgb(255, 99, 132, 0.4)') // with opacity
  ]
}]
```

But its not working. normal colors are working but not with pattern.